# How to unwind json

Tags: python, json

I have a text file with json object in each line as below. Can i know what are some of the ways to unwind the json  using pandas.

```
{"resource":{"resourceType":"bund","id":"c4356","extension":[{"url":"member","valueString":"covid"},{"url":"complaint","valueString":"ache"},{"url":"code","valueCodeableConcept":{"id":"797fe48b","coding":[{"system":"followup","code":"choice","display":"Please followup"}]}}],"identifier":[{"use":"primary","system":"consult","value":"3867"},{"use":"secondary","system":"visit","value":"9089"},{"use":"third","system":"kjhd","value":"972e68"}],"codes":[56,86,65]}}
{"resource":{"resourceType":"bund","id":"dvdv6","extension":[{"url":"member","valueString":"covid"},{"url":"complaint","valueString":"stomach"},{"url":"code","valueCodeableConcept":{"id":"9765e48b","coding":[{"system":"followup","code":"choice","display":"Please followup"}]}}],"identifier":[{"use":"primary","system":"consult","value":"3867"},{"use":"secondary","system":"visit","value":"8789"},{"use":"third","system":"kjhd","value":"872e68"}],"codes":[76,89,90]}}
```

I attempted the code using json_normalize.

Comment: It's sounding like you need a custom parser to flatten out the data before putting it into pandas? Why not write your own parser?

Answer (score 2):

Using

- `json_normalize()`
- `explode()` of embedded lists (`reset_index()` so that joins will work)
- `apply(pd.Series)` joining back to dataframe of embedded dicts
- a bit of cleanup to drop embedded dicts

```
import json, io
s = """{"deleted_flg":false,"resource":{"resourceType":"bund","id":"c4356","extension":[{"url":"member","valueString":"covid"},{"url":"complaint","valueString":"ache"},{"url":"code","valueCodeableConcept":{"id":"797fe48b","coding":[{"system":"followup","code":"choice","display":"Please followup"}]}}],"identifier":[{"use":"primary","system":"consult","value":"3867"},{"use":"secondary","system":"visit","value":"9089"},{"use":"third","system":"kjhd","value":"972e68"}],"codes":[56,86,65]}}
{"deleted_flg":true,"resource":{"resourceType":"bund","id":"dvdv6","extension":[{"url":"member","valueString":"covid"},{"url":"complaint","valueString":"stomach"},{"url":"code","valueCodeableConcept":{"id":"9765e48b","coding":[{"system":"followup","code":"choice","display":"Please followup"}]}}],"identifier":[{"use":"primary","system":"consult","value":"3867"},{"use":"secondary","system":"visit","value":"8789"},{"use":"third","system":"kjhd","value":"872e68"}],"codes":[76,89,90]}}"""
s = s.replace("\n",",")
s = f"[{s}]"
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)).explode("resource.extension").explode("resource.identifier").explode("resource.codes").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df["resource.extension"].apply(pd.Series)).join(df["resource.identifier"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=["resource.extension","resource.identifier"])
df = df.join(df["valueCodeableConcept"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=["valueCodeableConcept",0]).explode("coding").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df["coding"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_coding").drop(columns=["coding",0])
```

|  | deleted_flg | resource.resourceType | resource.id | resource.codes | url | valueString | use | system | value | id | code | display | system_coding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 6 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 7 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 8 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 9 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | complaint | ache | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 10 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | complaint | ache | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 11 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | complaint | ache | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 12 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | complaint | ache | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 13 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | complaint | ache | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 14 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | complaint | ache | secondary | visit | 9089 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 15 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | complaint | ache | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 16 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | complaint | ache | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 17 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | complaint | ache | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 18 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 19 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 20 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 21 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 9089 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 22 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 9089 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 23 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 9089 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 24 | False | bund | c4356 | 56 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 25 | False | bund | c4356 | 86 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 26 | False | bund | c4356 | 65 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 9.72e+70 | 797fe48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 27 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 28 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 29 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | member | covid | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 30 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 31 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 32 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | member | covid | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 33 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 34 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 35 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | member | covid | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 36 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | complaint | stomach | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 37 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | complaint | stomach | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 38 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | complaint | stomach | primary | consult | 3867 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 39 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | complaint | stomach | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 40 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | complaint | stomach | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 41 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | complaint | stomach | secondary | visit | 8789 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 42 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | complaint | stomach | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 43 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | complaint | stomach | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 44 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | complaint | stomach | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 45 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 46 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 47 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | code | nan | primary | consult | 3867 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 48 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 8789 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 49 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 8789 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 50 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | code | nan | secondary | visit | 8789 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 51 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 76 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 52 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 89 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |
| 53 | True | bund | dvdv6 | 90 | code | nan | third | kjhd | 8.72e+70 | 9765e48b | choice | Please followup | followup |